# Visual Studio 2008 Crashes When Opening Project Properties

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crash

I have a multi-project .NET application which I am developing in Visual Studio 2008.  If I try to open the project properties for one of my projects (to change settings or publish) Visual Studio immediately closes. There is no prompt to send a report to Microsoft, and two consecutive errors logged in the Event Viewer:

- .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 -
  Fatal Execution Engine Error
  (7A035E00) (80131506)
- .NET Runtime    version
  2.0.50727.3053 - Fatal    Execution Engine Error (7A2E0F92) (0)

If I delete all the `.user` and `.suo` files in my solution, I can once again publish and access project properties.  The error, however, returns over time.  This seems to suggest that the `.suo` or `.user` files are getting corrupted by Visual Studio.  Has anyone else had this issue or know how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turn off all of your add-ins and try again. Use Tools->Add-in Manager.

If that doesn't help, run VS in "safe mode", by using `devenv /safemode` from a Visual Studio Command Prompt window.

Comment: I have the same problem, the solution did not work.  I have no Addin installed, and I can't open my project in safemode.  It says "It is not supported by this installation".

Comment: +1 I solved my problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198935/resource-editor-not-available-in-visual-studio-2008) first doing **devenv /safemode** and then watching in the VS output that some package was not loaded due to previous errors and to load it again I should try **devenv /resetskippkgs**. I did it and, voilà! Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I deleted files with following extensions in project folder (I don't know which one was important...) -> suo, user, cachefile

Comment: also for me, but also got rid of expired *.reshaper file.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in the CLR which affects add-ins (see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/cb73c8d6-077f-4220-aaf8-463039ee1d5f/)). Are you running any add-ins, and have you updated Visual Studio and the .NET framework to the latest service pack?

Comment: I am running the ReSharper add-in.  I'll disable that and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what really caused the problem, but I could fix it by ***File -> Source Control -> Refresh status***

Answer (score 0):

VS2008 would disappear when I attempted to open project properties.   Finally solved it by doing a clean on the solution.   Many hours of frustration wasted when the cure (at least in my case) was so simple (-:).

Answer (score 0):

When opening the project properties cause Visual Studio to crash. I found out that cleaning and ++not** rebuilding the soulution worked reliably. I have no add-ons but program WPF and have had quite a few issues with WPF/vs not wanting to cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today that was solved by uninstalling Power Commands for Visual Studio 2008.  If you have this installed, I recommend removing it and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Everytime I open the project properties or a resource file (.resx) vs2008 will stop responding and the task manager will show the cpu utilisation as 100%. I solved it by deleting the .suo file in the solutions folder and got a fresh copy from the source control and then from the VS2008 command prompt I typed in "devenv /resetskippkgs" . This restarted VS2008 and I could open my resources files and also the project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have experienced it many times. The problem goes away if I delete all the view private files (we use ClearCase here), .suo and .user included.