# Resource editor not available in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resources, projects-and-solutions

When I right-click on a resource file in Visual Studio 2008, I get the following message:

> There is no editor available for
>   'D:\MyPath\MyProject\Resources.de.resx'.
>   Make sure the application for the file
>   type (.resx) is installed.

Any idea on how to solve this issue? By now, I am stuck with opening the resource files as XML text.

I am working with Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition.

**Update:**

Unfortunately (for me), uninstalling and installing again Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition and its service pack did not solve the problem.

Incidentally, I cannot see any C# Project Properties page, either. When I try to show them, nothing happens.

**Update 2:**

I finally solved my problem. I added an [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198935/resource-editor-not-available-in-visual-studio-2008/3298303#3298303) explaining how.

Comment: A good question, have the same problem in 2012 and 2013. Don't understand why that's suddenly been taken out. I used to always have these files, also in 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. What I did, inspired by [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752885/visual-studio-2008-crashes-when-opening-project-properties/752898#752898), was:

- Reinstall Visual Studio - to no success. Looking at it retrospectively, maybe my uninstall wasn't complete - but I really *thought* I had uninstalled it.
- Start Visual Studio in safe mode: from the Windows command prompt (Start|Run...), type `devenv /safemode`.
- At the Project menu, click Properties. A message appeared saying that some relevant package (something like Project Designer) had not been loaded due to previous errors, and I could load it again by starting Visual Studio with `devenv /resetskippkgs`. After doing so, the project properties are loaded normally. As a consequence, the resources, which belong to these properties, can be viewed.

So, to summarize, I just needed to take advantage of `devenv /safemode`, after which Visual Studio suggested me to use `devenv /resetskippkgs`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the file type association for RESX? Reset the assocations: Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Reset File Associations

You may also want to try a repair install on Visual Studio (if you have the time...)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Resetting the file associations did not solve my problem. I am going to try a repair install later.

Comment: No fun. You may be better off posting in the MSDN forums, some of the developers frequent there and can give better insight.