# Add Company Name, Product Name, etc to Mixed Mode Assembly DLL

Tags: c++-cli, mixed-mode, assemblyinfo

I'm building a mixed-mode assembly with C++/CLI but I can't figure out how to add standard Windows Assembly attributes like Company Name, Copyright, Product Name, Version, etc. There isn't a resource file that works like `AssemblyInfo.cs` does in C#. I tried Add->Resource->Version but that just gives me a standard `ProjectName.rc`. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: What is wrong with the standard rc file???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a while to figure out, and the GUI is buggy so I finally edited it by hand. I've pasted the final contents of my `ProjectName.rc` that generates proper Windows Assembly Properties. You can just create an RC file and paste this into it.

If your project is an EXE project, replace `FILETYPE 0x2L` with `FILETYPE 0x1L`

```
#include <windows.h>

LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
// 
// Version
// 

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 1,0,0,1
 PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,1
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x40004L
 FILETYPE 0x2L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "Comments", "Sample Application"
            VALUE "CompanyName", "My Company"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "My Application"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1, 0, 0, 1"
            VALUE "InternalName", "MyProject"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (C) My Company 1999"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "MyProject.dll"
            VALUE "ProductName", "MyProject"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1, 0, 0, 1"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard rc-file will give you the standard version info, which can be seen in explorer by right-clicking the file and selecting "Properties".

[image] [image]

The assembly infos can be inserted with the assembly attributes:

```
[assembly:AssemblyTitleAttribute("MCPP_Console")];
[assembly:AssemblyDescriptionAttribute("")];
[assembly:AssemblyConfigurationAttribute("")];
[assembly:AssemblyCompanyAttribute("??")];
[assembly:AssemblyProductAttribute("MCPP_Console")];
[assembly:AssemblyCopyrightAttribute("Copyright (c) ?? 2014")];
[assembly:AssemblyTrademarkAttribute("")];
[assembly:AssemblyCultureAttribute("")];
[assembly:AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0")];
```

Comment: Yes, but after adding the std RC file, how do I get the editor like you have shown in the screenshot?

Comment: Do I have to type the code you have shown in the RC file? Is that C++/CLI code or C# code?

Comment: Just double click the rc file... if you have the express edition, then you might edit the resource file by "hand" in a text editor...

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198935/resource-editor-not-available-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: If you right-clik on the rc-file and select "Properties", does it display: "Item type: Resopurce compiler"?